# Is there any way without using -U or -P parameter to login to openedge application

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Suppose we have enabled the "disable blank userid access" option in database options, then is there any way without using -U or -P parameter to login to openedge or progress application?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please brief the exact use case? I think we can login using OpenEdge SQL. Not sure!

Comment: Situation 1 - If user try to open _edit.p it should ask for userid and password.

Comment: Situation 2 - Some one should not able connect the DB without user id and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid both the interactive login and the use of -U and -P by implementing the CLIENT-PRINCIPLE object and using that to assert an identity prior to attempting to access data.

A good place to start: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P147947

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on your version of Progress from my reading. I believe though that if you're on a reasonably modern version of Progress (10.2B or later) then there is no way to access the data without a -U or -P parameter. It should be used in conjunction with the 'use runtime permissions checking' option. I hope this helps.

Comment: I want the same the 'use runtime permissions checking' option. without a -U or -P parameter. Can I have some examples how it can be done.

Comment: You must have a userid to access data -- but you can assert a userid without using -U and -P.  If nothing else the default interactive login does that for you.